# How to turn on the screen on a Mac iBook G3

Tags: mac, power-supply, display, ibook

I have an iBook G3 that was bought for cheap. When I press a button on the bottom of the laptop, a light turns on in the front. After several minutes, the light flashes like the laptop is in sleep mode.

Even after the light comes on in the front, the screen does not turn on. I didn't receive a power supply with this laptop, butr I heard that buying a power supply will fix this problem. Is that true? How do you turn on the screen?

Comment: The screen might be on minimum brightness. On two of your F-keys, there are symbolic suns, one is big, one is small. Press the "big sun" key repeatedly after turning it on, both with and without simultaneously pressing Fn.

Comment: Also, your machine is at least 8 years old, there's a possibility it's  broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't receive a power supply with this laptop.

Well, the most obvious suggestion is that the battery is nearly flat and the poor thing shuts itself down immediately on the start-up attempt.

If you look at the battery underneath you will find it has a series of LEDs and a small button. Pushing the button will tell you how much juice the battery has. (Or not). In any case, you're not going to get much use out of it without a power supply.